# Calling Google Now search programmatically from Android application

Tags: android, android-intent, google-now

I have a text box and a button. When I click on the button Google Now is triggered with the text in the text box. I am using the below function to launch the Google Now with the text.

```
    public void searchWeb(String query)
    {
      Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_WEB_SEARCH);
      intent.putExtra(SearchManager.QUERY, query);
      intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
      intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_MULTIPLE_TASK);
      startActivity(intent);
    }
```

The problem is I could open the Google Now with my text only when it's not in running state. When it's in the running state,the Google Now page opens but the search query is not updated with the latest one.

Am I missing something?

Answer (score 2):

Further investigating on this issue, I found out that I am wrongly using the setting flags method. Here, I have to use addflags method instead of setFlags, so code would work without any problems.

```
    public void searchWeb(String query)
    {
      Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_WEB_SEARCH);
      intent.putExtra(SearchManager.QUERY, query);
      intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
      intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_MULTIPLE_TASK);
      startActivity(intent);
    }
```

Comment: You miss understood the question, your code is for google now, what i am looking for is the code for the Google Assistant introduce in the Pixel phones with android 7.x.